# Correct translation of Nirukta 2.6

Tags: translation-request, nirukta, yaska

What is the translation of [Nirukta 2.6](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83)?

> वृक्षवृक्षे वियता मीमय॒द् गौस्ततो वयः प्र प॑तान्पूरुषादः । वृक्षवृक्षे
> धनुषिधनुषि । वृत्वा क्षां तिष्ठतीति वा । क्षा क्षियतेः । निवासकर्मणेः
> नियता मीमयद् गौः शब्दं करोति । मीमयतिः शब्दकर्मा । ततो वयः प्रपतन्ति ।
> पुरुषानदनाय । विरिति शकुनिनाम । वेतेर्गतिकर्मणः । अथापीषुनामेह
> भवत्येतस्मादेव । आदित्योऽपि गौरुच्यते । उतादः परुषे गवि । पर्ववति
> भास्वतीत्यौपमन्यवः । अथाप्यस्यैको रश्मिश्चंद्रमसं प्रति दीप्यते
> तदेतेनोपेक्षितव्यम् । आदित्यतोऽस्य दीप्तिर्भवति । सुषुम्णः
> सूर्यरश्मिश्चन्द्रमा गन्धर्वः । इत्यपि निगमो भवति । सोऽपि गौरुच्यते ।
> अत्राह गोरमन्वत । इति । तदुपरिष्टाद् व्याख्यास्यामः । सर्वेऽपि रश्मयो
> गाव उच्यन्ते ॥ २.६ ॥

And, please mention the mistakes made by Lakshman Sarup in translating the Nirukta written by Yaska?

Comment: Questions asking for translation of particular verse from text of which translations are available, are off-topic. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1676/277) for more information.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. If you're looking for translation of Nirukta in a particular language, then edit the question accordingly to mention it 2. If you're finding difficulty in getting the meaning of the quoted verse then edit the question to describe what problem you're facing with the translation you're referring

Comment: Please translate

Comment: What mistake are you talking about?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: By its nature, translation can be done multiple ways "correctly." No translation will convey 100% of the semantic and pragmatic context—let alone the cultural context of a particular period of time or location. As such, any translation questions must here be considered "opinion-based." This is better suited to a Sanskrit language oriented SE.